# Consolidating slots in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How can I reduce the number of `pyqtSlot()` functions so that I don't need to have two of each? It seems like there should be a better way of doing this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

The code takes two files, reads each file on different threads, and prints the outputs to different `QPlainTextEdit` objects.

```
import sys
import time
import traceback
import pandas as pd

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from compare_files_gui import Ui_MainWindow


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    """Defines signals from running worker thread."""
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(str)
    progress = pyqtSignal(str)
    bar = pyqtSignal(int)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    """Worker thread."""
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress
        self.kwargs['pbar'] = self.signals.bar

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.compare)
        self.ui.file1_progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.ui.file2_progressBar.setValue(0)

        self.ui.file1_lineEdit.setText('file1.csv')
        self.ui.file2_lineEdit.setText('file2.csv')
        self.file1 = self.ui.file1_lineEdit.text()
        self.file2 = self.ui.file2_lineEdit.text()

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()

    ##### How can I consolidate the following slots so I don't need to
    ##### have 2, one for each console object?
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def progress_fn1(self, n):
        self.ui.console1_plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(n)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def progress_fn2(self, n):
        self.ui.console2_plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(n)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def print_output1(self, s):
        self.ui.console1_plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(s)

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def print_output2(self, s):
        self.ui.console2_plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(s)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def thread_complete1(self):
        self.ui.console1_plainTextEdit.appendPlainText('Processing complete!')

    @pyqtSlot()
    def thread_complete2(self):
        self.ui.console2_plainTextEdit.appendPlainText('Processing complete!')

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def update_progress1(self, v):
        self.ui.file1_progressBar.setValue(v)

    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def update_progress2(self, v):
        self.ui.file2_progressBar.setValue(v)

    def compare(self):
        # files = [self.ui.file1_lineEdit.text(), self.ui.file2_lineEdit.text()]
        files = [self.file1, self.file2]

        # Start new thread for each file
        for i, file in enumerate(files, 1):
            worker = Worker(self.process_file, file)

            #### Is there a better way to do this?
            if i == 1:
                worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn1)
                worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output1)
                worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete1)
                worker.signals.bar.connect(self.update_progress1)
            elif i == 2:
                worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn2)
                worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output2)
                worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete2)
                worker.signals.bar.connect(self.update_progress2)
            else:
                pass

            # Execute thread
            self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def process_file(self, file, pbar, progress_callback):
        """Process file and emit signals."""
        t0 = time.time()
        progress_callback.emit(f'Processing {file}')

        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=['col'])

        num = len(df.index)

        for i, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
            progress_callback.emit('  ' + row['col'])
            pbar.emit(int(i*100/num))
            time.sleep(0.25)

        t1 = time.time()

        return f'Time to complete: {round(t1-t0, 3)} s'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Many of your slots are actually unnecessary. For instance, you could directly connect to `self.ui.file1_progressBar.setValue` instead of using `update_progress1, which does absolutely nothing else. The same for the text that just add the received text. Also, consider that slots are not always necessary, and you can usually use the plain python function.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, I passed on the `QPlainTextEdit` and `QProgressBar` objects associated with each file to the thread, and then emitted those from the thread, so that I could determine which `QPlainTextEdit` to print to. From what I've read online, I don't think passing UI objects to background threads is a best practice, but it works for this simple application and I haven't been able to figure out a better way to do it.

```
import sys
import time
import traceback
import pandas as pd

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from compare_files_gui import Ui_MainWindow


class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    """Defines signals from running worker thread."""
    finished = pyqtSignal(object)
    error = pyqtSignal(tuple)
    result = pyqtSignal(object, str)
    progress = pyqtSignal(object, str)
    bar = pyqtSignal(object, int)


class Worker(QRunnable):
    """Worker thread."""
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        # Store constructor arguments
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

        # Add callbacks to kwargs
        self.kwargs['progress_callback'] = self.signals.progress
        self.kwargs['pbar_callback'] = self.signals.bar

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        try:
            console, result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exctype, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
            self.signals.error.emit((exctype, value, traceback.format_exc()))
        else:
            self.signals.result.emit(console, result)
        finally:
            self.signals.finished.emit(console)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Initialize progress bars
        self.ui.file1_progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.ui.file2_progressBar.setValue(0)

        # Connect widgets to slots
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.compare)

        # Create instance of QThreadPool
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()


    @pyqtSlot(object, str)
    def progress_fn(self, console, n):
        """Print progress string to specific QPlainTextEdit object."""
        console.appendPlainText(n)

    @pyqtSlot(object, str)
    def print_output(self, console, s):
        """Print result string to specific QPlainTextEdit object."""
        console.appendPlainText(s)

    @pyqtSlot(object)
    def thread_complete(self, console):
        """Print completion text to specific QPlainTextEdit object."""
        console.appendPlainText('Processing complete!')

    @pyqtSlot(object, int)
    def update_progress(self, pbar, v):
        """Set value of QProgressBar object."""
        pbar.setValue(v)

    def compare(self):
        """Send each file and associated UI objects to thread."""
        # Store files in list
        # files = [self.ui.file1_lineEdit.text(), self.ui.file2_lineEdit.text()]
        files = [self.file1, self.file2]

        # Store QPlainTextEdit and QProgressBar objects in list
        consoles = [self.ui.console1_plainTextEdit, self.ui.console2_plainTextEdit]
        pbars = [self.ui.file1_progressBar, self.ui.file2_progressBar]

        # Start new thread for each file
        for i, (file, console, pbar) in enumerate(zip(files, consoles, pbars), 1):
            worker = Worker(self.process_file, file, console, pbar)

            # Connect thread signals to slots in UI thread
            worker.signals.progress.connect(self.progress_fn)
            worker.signals.result.connect(self.print_output)
            worker.signals.finished.connect(self.thread_complete)
            worker.signals.bar.connect(self.update_progress)

            # Execute thread
            self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def process_file(self, file, console, pbar, pbar_callback, progress_callback):
        """Process file and emit signals."""
        t0 = time.time()

        progress_callback.emit(console, f'Processing {file}')

        # Read file into dataframe
        df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None, names=['col'])

        # Iterate over each row and emit value of column and progress
        num = len(df.index)
        for i, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
            progress_callback.emit(console, '  ' + row['col'])
            pbar_callback.emit(pbar, int(i*100/num))

            # Slow down response
            time.sleep(0.25)

        t1 = time.time()

        # Return QPlainTextEdit object and string
        return console, f'Time to complete: {round(t1-t0, 3)} s'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```